# Making a div of 100% height

Tags: html, css

I'm designing ad admin panel for my website and first of all i have a top Navigation Bar in Wrapper and after that i have 2 more div's .

1.For side navigation menu (on left)

2.For rest of the page content (on right)

I want my side navigation menu to cover the entire height of the screen. but somehow i failed to do that, i have tried the following attempts.

1st attempt (html code)

```css
.mainSideNavBar {
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 63px;
  height: 100%;
}
.sideNavBar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #303641;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #454a54;
  height: 100%;
}
.mainPageContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.pageContent {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 20%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease, padding-left 0.5s ease;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="mainSideNavBar">
    <div class="sideNavBar" id="sideNavBar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-television"></i><span class="" id="textHideD">Dashboard</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span class="" id="textHideN">Notifications</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span class="" id="textHideM">Manages Users</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i><span class="" id="textHideB">Bet Management</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i><span class="" id="textHideR">Modify Rules</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i><span class="" id="textHideP">Payment</span></a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--End sideNavBar-->
  </div>
  <!--End mainSideNavBar-->

  <div class="mainPageContent">
    <div class="pageContent" id="pageContent">
      <h1>My Content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem with this code is, it works perfect if the content in .PageContent class is smaller than the screen height (no scroll bar showing), but when the content in the .PageContent class is larger than the current screen height (scroll bar showing) then my left side navigation shows a small gap between top navigation and it self because of (position:fixed).

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screen Shot]

And in my second attempt, i change my position:fixed to position:absolute and then a new problem appears, 
Side bar navigation collapse half of the height of the current screen height with a scroll bar

[image: Screen Shot]

Css code for html, and body

```
html , body{height:100%;}
```

I'm stuck, suggest me some good(proper) way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove absolute or fixed positioning for your sidebar.

Just set it as `float: left;`, keeping you current width (20%).

Then, for your `.mainPageContent`, set it as `float: right;` and fill the width in '%' with the padding-left and the width of your content.

Then, for the height, I'm using `min-height: 100vh;` which guarantees to fill all the height of the screen (vh = view height) and is pretty well supported by browsers.

So you can set `min-height: 100vh;` on your sidebar, I think it will do the trick.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

As you're using fixed positioning, instead of setting the `height` to be `100%`, use the `top` & `bottom` properties, giving `top` a value equal to the height of your header and `bottom` a value of `0`.